# How to apply new textwidth to whole buffer in Vim

Tags: vim

I've changed the `textwidth` option mid-way through my file and I'd like to reformat the whole buffer to use the new width. What's the quickest way to do this?

---

#### Solution - Vim documentation topic

### [gq](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#gq)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See

```
:help gq
```

if it helps.

Answer (score 10):

```
gq<motion>
```

For example, if your file consists of 100 lines, move to the first line and then press:

```
gq100<Down Arrow>
```

You can use the visual mode to select the lines and then press `gq` as well.

Comment: Should add the V selection and them gq, I particularly think that it is the best solution (in the case to reshape only one paragraph, for exemple, use vip or vap then gq).